# Android Reminder with Auto sms app

Tags: android, sms, reminders

I am new to Android willing to create an app for auto message on scheduled date and time with alarm setup too for a min version of jelly bean and max version 21

How do i start with it?? Which all android classes do I need to refer for developing this app for it being compatible to both versions  please help..

Comment: Study about broadcast receivers,sms manager,pending intent,calander classes 
these concepts will help you to solve your problem 
good luck !!

Comment: Also about Alarm manager and notification manager to show sms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/telephony/smsmanager/android-sending-sms-example/

and here is the answer for your problem @Diya

Comment: Thank you...but can u suggest anything about calender with alarm on reminders too??

Comment: Its my pleasure 
after implementing sms regarding code,you have to understand about Alarm manager,calender,broadcast receiver and pending intent 

you can take help from it 

http://www.steventrigg.com/alarm-manager-create-an-alarm-clock-in-android-tutorial-part-6/

Comment: After this you have to combine both the examples 
which will solve your problem @Diya